# auto specifier in header file

Tags: c++, header-files, auto

I have a file `Foo.h`:

```cpp
// Foo.h
#pragma once

int foo();
```

Also I have a `Foo.cpp` file which implements `Foo.h`:

```cpp
//Foo.cpp
#include "Foo.h"

int foo() {
    return 5;
}
```

Is there a way to make `foo` function return type `auto`? It may be useful if I create a function which return value depends on 3rd party library functions, which return value types may change in later versions.

Comment: `auto foo();` is essentially shorthand for `template <typename T> T foo();`, and the compiler needs to be able to infer the return type from the code. If you just want to avoid spelling out a type that's defined elsewhere, use a type alias or define your own type that hides the library type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do that, you need to put the *definition* of the function (not just the declaration) into the header file. Otherwise, how can the compiler tell the type of `foo` if it is called from another source file?

And if you want to define a function in a header file, you need to declare it inline, otherwise the linker will complain of multiple definitions.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to make foo function return type auto?

Only by defining the function inline. Which contradicts with your premise that the function is defined in a separate translation unit.

> It may be useful if I create a function which return value depends on 3rd party library functions

You can use a type alias for this purpose:

```
using return_type = 
    std::invoke_result<library_function, some_arg_t>;
return_type foo();
```